The language is set from different domains with Polylang
I have a WordPress website with a Polylang plugin for multilingual. I want to set different language to different domain. That's why I selected The language is set from different domains option. 
https://www.imagevenue.com/ME17ZY27 . 
e.g. 
I have a website like https://ne.main_domain.nl/ (Nederlands version). I want to switch to https://en.main_domain.nl/ with language switcher. I set up my WordPress in https://ne.main_domain.nl/ . But I did not setup WordPress in https://en.main_domain.nl/ which is for the English version. Only I put index.php (WordPress file) file there. When I try to switch the language there are shown the message like below:
This page isn’t working
en.main_domain.nl is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
I read this article https://polylang.pro/doc/url-modifications/#subdomains-name-and-domains . But I can not understand what is wrong with my procedure. Do I need to setup WordPress in https://en.main_domain.nl/ also? I searched for articles and video tutorials for this. But not succeed. Any idea?
Thanks.

I have found the solution at last. You don't need to install WordPress for another domain (https://en.main_domain.nl/). Just put the https://ne.main_domain.nl/ for https://en.main_domain.nl/ in the Document root field (Follow Hosting Settings -> Hosting type). These settings are for the Plesk server.
